# Rewrite CASE to COALESCE

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have part  of code in my query , that have CASE, and I want to rewrite it to COALESCE

Here is original part of code

```
CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE u.ClientCharges END -
                            CASE WHEN LAGClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0
                            ELSE LAGClientCharges
                            END AS my_Delta,

    CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE u.ClientCharges END - CASE WHEN LAGClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0
                            ELSE LAGClientCharges END) > 0 THEN 'Gain'
         WHEN CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE u.ClientCharges END - CASE WHEN LAGClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0
                            ELSE LAGClientCharges END < 0 THEN 'Loss'
                            ELSE NULL END AS GainsLosses,
    CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges >=0 AND LAGClientCharges IS NULL AND t.MonthBilled <> '2015-01-01' THEN 'New' ELSE 'Existing' END AS ClientType,

    CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 'InActive' ELSE 'Active' END AS ActiveStatus,

    CASE WHEN LAGClientCharges IS NOT NULL AND t.MonthBilled <> '2015-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS ActiveLastMonth,

    CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL AND (LAGClientCharges <> 0 AND LAGClientCharges IS NOT NULL) AND t.MonthBilled <> '1/1/2015' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS OneMonthChurn,

    u2.FeatureKeyCount,

    CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NOT NULL AND u.ClientCharges > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OrgCounter
```

Here is part , where I rewrite some of CASE statements

```
    COALESCE(u.ClientCharges, 0) - COALESCE(LAGClientCharges, 0) AS my_Delta,

    CASE WHEN (COALESCE(u.ClientCharges , 0) - COALESCE(LAGClientCharges , 0)) > 0 THEN 'Gain'
         WHEN COALESCE (u.ClientCharges , 0) - COALESCE(LAGClientCharges , 0) < 0 THEN 'Loss'
                            ELSE NULL END AS GainsLosses,
    CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges >=0 AND LAGClientCharges IS NULL AND t.MonthBilled <> '2015-01-01' THEN 'New' ELSE 'Existing' END AS ClientType,

   COALESCE (u.ClientCharges, 'InActive') AS ActiveStatus,

    CASE WHEN LAGClientCharges IS NOT NULL AND t.MonthBilled <> '2015-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS ActiveLastMonth,

    CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL AND (LAGClientCharges <> 0 AND LAGClientCharges IS NOT NULL) AND t.MonthBilled <> '2015-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS OneMonthChurn,

    u2.FeatureKeyCount,

    CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NOT NULL AND u.ClientCharges > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OrgCounter
```

But how I can rewrite rows with AND, or maybe it has some better variant , how to rewrite it?

Comment: Simplify your example! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What's the question?  You seem to know how to use `COALESCE` the way you want.

Comment: Question is how to rewrite rows with `AND` correctly. For example this `CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges >=0 AND LAGClientCharges IS NULL AND t.MonthBilled <> '2015-01-01' THEN 'New' ELSE 'Existing' END AS ClientType,` @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: `coalesce(a,b)` is a shortcut for a specific case: `case when a is not null the a else b end`, it's neither faster nor slower, just a bit shorter syntax. Like `case x when ...` is a shortcut for `case when x = ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question appears to be that you are struggling to re-write the logic for the case's that involve `AND`

```
CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NOT NULL AND u.ClientCharges > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OrgCounter
```

It's debatable whether it is clearer for the reader, but you are asking for logic along these lines:

```
CASE WHEN coalesce(u.ClientCharges,0) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OrgCounter
```

This works when the clauses in the `AND` are using the same field, but for the ones where you are checking multiple different fields, you need to leave them as they are.

A lot of interpretation of the data is going on within this piece of code - in effect business logic is being embedded into the SQL - you may wish to reconsider that.